# VB.NET System.collections.ArrayList cannot converted to class as List

Tags: vb.net

I am facing issue in the below VB.NET code when tried to add in the list. How to solve this
I posted this issue as another question.

My idea is to achieve below Java code in VB.NET. how to write Arrays.asList in VB.NET

```
userArray.getUsr().addAll(Arrays.asList(userArr));


        Dim UsertestArray As UserArray = New UserArray()  
       Dim userArray(1) As Usertest 
       Dim usertest As Usertest 
       Dim lines As ArrayList = New ArrayList()
       userArray(0) = Usertest           { **Usertest containes data from DB**)
       lines.Add(userArray)
         Dim intList As New List(Of Usertest)
          intList.AddRange(userArray)
          UsertestArray.getUsr.AddRange(intList) 
         Return UsertestArray  { ** When I tried to Return UserTestArray it shows UserArray cannot be converted to Usertest}


UserArray class:

Protected usr As List(Of Usertest )

Public Function getUsr() As List(Of Usertest )
    If (Me.usr Is Nothing) Then
        Me.usr = New List(Of Usertest )()
    End If

    Return Me.usr
```

Java code:

```
         Usertest[] userArr = new Usertest[1];
        try {
            userArr[0] = DBUtilstest.getUser(id);
            userArray.getUsr().addAll(Arrays.asList(userArr));
            return userArray;
        } catch (Exception e) {

   protected List<Usertest> usr;
   public List<Usertest> getUsr() {
    if (usr == null) {
        usr = new ArrayList<Usertest>();
    }
    return this.usr;
}
```

Comment: It´s pretty simple and the error message is descriptive. You cannot add `ArrayList` to `List(Of Usertmo)`. `UsertestArray.getUsr.Add` expects a `Usertmo` and nothing else. Is there any inheritance between `Usertmo` and `Usertest` ?

Comment: Hi Thanks for you reply. I updated the code which I pasted mistake. There is no Usertmo only Usertest. Please help on this

Comment: I'd recommend to avoid arrays unless you need them.  `List(Of T)` is best for most uses, and it looks like you're already using it.  If you need to convert a list to an array, see `ToArray` (which may require you to import the `System.Linq` namespace).

Comment: You're also not showing enough of the Java code to give a good answer here.  What is `userArray`?  What is `getUsr`?

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. Updated with java code and UserArray is class and getUsr is a method which will return a ArrayList

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList` in VB.  Keep everything as a `List(Of T)`.  Then, the replacement for `addAll` will be `AddRange` (this will add all items from an `IEnumerable(Of T)` to a `List(Of T)`).

Comment: Updated the code as per the comment but i am getting error When I tried to Return UserTestArray it shows UserArray cannot be converted to Usertest. Any thing i need to cast. Please help on this. I am new to VB.NET